# troubles including Jquery library in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have trouble including Jquery in my HTML page. I'm trying to display a calendar clicking on a button, but the calendar is not showing up. The following error showed up : $(..)Datapicker is not a function. I've looked up on internet, and people said it was because of multiple including. But I'm pretty sure that I've only included Jquery once, because when I remove the Jquery include, it says that I do not include it. Here is the header:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
  </script>  
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6cd7c64e2b.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/css/control/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/css/control/ir-button.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/css/recorder/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/js/recorder/timer.js"></script>
```

Note that the js script is in the header because I wanted to test it as it was not working in an external file!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You missed to load jQuery library, and make sure its at the top

Comment: Load jquery before jquery UI.....

Comment: You haven't included jquery - you've included jquery-ui - you also need jquery *before* jquery-ui

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've done what you said, but I still get the same error..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery` (*core*) too. Actually you only added `jQuery UI`, witch is an extension for jQuery itself.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And are you sure using such an old version of jQuery UI? Current version of jQuery UI is `1.12.0`, working with all jQuery versions since 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. Unfortunately, I just did what you said, but the calendar is still not showing up, and the error $(...)datapicker is not a function, is still here.. Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: Did it say `datapicker` or `datepicker`? I should be named `datepicker`, as in your example code.

Comment: My bad, I meant datepicker

Comment: Then there is something else broken in your code. See this example, it is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gj5L69LL/. You can try `jQuery` instead of `$`, maybe it runs in `noConflict` mode by Angular. Like this: `jQuery(function($) { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); });`

Comment: It actually worked!! Any idea why? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the `$` is used by many libraries. I think Angular registers even something one that. So the `$` has been overwritten and now your jQuery instance runs in `noConflict` mode. Means that jQuery is only availabel over `jQuery`. So you can use the code like above and you'll be fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it by following order and version of jquery files. Check below code snippet.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type=text id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Eisbehr just solved my problem, but thanks for responding!